# How to perform xsl transformation if custom namespaces are used

Tags: xml, xslt

Source xml contains custom namespaces:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getBuyInvoiceResponse xmlns:ns="http://iws.itella.ee">
      <ns:return>
        <E_Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
```

XSL contaisn also those namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://iws.itella.ee"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

and they are used in selector

```
  <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getBuyInvoiceResponse/E_Invoice/Invoice/InvoiceItem/InvoiceItemGroup/*">
```

XSLT transformation using http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation creates empty document. How to fix this so that document content is also created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, `E_Invoice` is a child of `ns:return`, not `ns:getBuyInvoiceResponse` - so your 2nd template matches nothing.

Note also that a *match pattern* is different from a *select expression*: you don't need to spell out the full path. This:

```
<xsl:template match="InvoiceItemGroup/*">
```

would have worked just as well.

Finally, note that you only need to use `xsl:element` if the element's name must be calculated. Otherwise it's shorter and better to use *literal result elements*.